# How do I print what was replaced in a substitution operation?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I understand that's a very simple question but I really failed googling it. =(

I've got something like this:

```
$a =~ s/(\w*)/--word was here--/g;
```

And I want to put into a log file which words were replaced.

`aa 123 bb 234 cc` → `--word was here-- 123 --word was here-- 234 --word was here--`

And that's okay, but I want to remember `aa`, `bb` and `cc` and write into a log file. What should I do?

In fact I have a link remover script but I need to remember which links were removed. I tried to simplify my task for you but made it much harder to understand - sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `e` modifier which evaluates the right side as an expression:

```
   $a =~ s/(\w*)/log_it($1), ""/ge;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following stores all captured words into an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $s = 'cat dog';
my @words;
while ($s =~ s/(\w+)//) {
    push @words, $1;
}
print Dumper(\@words);

__END__
$VAR1 = [
          'cat',
          'dog'
        ];
```

Update:  Now that you have added input and output data, it looks like you want to exclude numbers.  In that case, you could use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[\w]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a loop instead of `/g;`:

```
my $string = "xxx ; yyy ; zzz";
my @replaced;
while ($string =~ s/(\w+)//) { push @replaced, $1 };
print join(",",@replaced);
# OUTPUT: xxx,yyy,zzz
```

Please note that `\w` is a WORD character, not an alphabet one, so it will match digits 0-9 as well.
If you only want to match letters, use `[[:alpha:]]` class